Unable to access getFragmentList()
I am trying to access getFragmentList() in a Model object, and I keep getting this error:
TypeError: Cannot read private member #O from an object whose class did not declare it

After experimenting, my best guess on what could be causing this issue is the private #frags properties in model. I'm not sure why the member is called #0 in the error as well?
Does someone have any ideas about this? Is there any way around this? Any help would be appreciated.
I am using the latest version of Autodesk Forge Viewer (v7).

Thanks to the working example provided by @varunpatil, I was able to figure out why I couldn't use getFragmentList(). I am trying to build a Vue 3 component with Autodesk Forge Viewer, and I had the viewer saved as a reactive ref. According to this post, Vue proxies these private fields, which means I could never access methods that use private fields.
To resolve the issue, I just didn't use a reactive ref and used a simple global variable.

const model = viewer.model;
const fragmentlist = model.getFragmentList();
console.log(fragmentlist.fragments);

This is working fine, you can test in the console in this sample.
